# Selecting SQL TOP N rows from group, row_number, rank not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, rank, row-number

In SQL Server, I have one table with following fields. I would like to get Top N rows from each group. I have tried following sql query with Rank() and Row_number() but rank and row numbers are not in sequence so not able to limit the rows.

Here is SQL query I tried, as you can see in result, rank column does not have sequential number so "where" clause will not work for top 3 rows for each group.

Similar result observed with ROW_NUMBER(), DENSE_RANK()

```
  SELECT Rs.RunID,rs.SiteCode,procedure_name,rs.total_cpu_time, rank
FROM (
    SELECT RunID, SiteCode,total_cpu_time, procedure_name, rank() 
      over (Partition BY sitecode
            ORDER BY total_cpu_time desc ) AS Rank

    FROM TopProcs 
 --   ) rs WHERE Rank between 1 and 15 and RunID = 1 and SiteCode in ('CAS', 'P01')
    ) rs WHERE  RunID = 1 and SiteCode in ('CAS', 'P01')
    order by SiteCode`
```

Here is output,

```
RunID   SiteCode    procedure_name           total_cpu_time rank
1        CAS        spDRSActivation            117039139161 1
1        CAS        spDRSSendChangesForGroup    155827022   2
1        CAS        spDRSMsgBuilderActivation   153595640   3
1        CAS        spGetChangeNotifications    360607      30
1        CAS        spDRSSendSyncComplete       100169      65
1        CAS        spSendRcmServiceBrokerMessage   88270       67
1        CAS        spLogEntry                  53466       78
1        P01        spDRSMsgBuilderActivation   62843590384 9
1        P01        spDRSSendChangesForGroup    62746448352 10
1        P01        spDrsSummarizeSendHistory   54443397908 13
1        P01        CH_SummarizePolicyRequests  35371363957 18
1        P01        spProcessDCMComplianceMsg   29790879064 25
1        P01        spUpdateComplianceDetails   22106121907 26
```

Comment: You have other RunIDs where those "missing" ranks are?

Comment: Try putting the where clause inside the innermost subquery.

Comment: WHERE  RunID = 1 and SiteCode in ('CAS', 'P01') should be inside.you should provide input sample data .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to get the `TOP N` result for the `sitecode` partition with `total_cpu_time` as order. You can put the `Where` clause inside if you need to filter data afterwords just filter in inner query.

You can use the `Row_Number()` instead of the `rank()`,

```
SELECT rs.RunID,rs.SiteCode,rs.procedure_name,rs.total_cpu_time, rn
FROM (
       SELECT 
            RunID,  
            SiteCode,
            total_cpu_time, 
            procedure_name, 
            Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteCode ORDER BY total_cpu_time DESC) AS rn
        FROM TopProcs 
        WHERE
           RunID = 1 
           AND SiteCode IN('CAS', 'P01')
    ) rs 
WHERE  
    rs.rn < 4
ORDER BY SiteCode
```

This will return the top 3 rows for each SiteCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DENSE_RANK just fine:

```
SELECT Ranked.[SiteCode], Ranked.[procedure_name], Ranked.[total_cpu_time]
FROM (
        SELECT [SiteCode], [procedure_name], [total_cpu_time], DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [SiteCode] ORDER BY [total_cpu_time] DESC) AS [Rank]
        FROM #TopProcs 
     ) Ranked
WHERE Ranked.[Rank] <= 3
```